# How to retrieve single document from azure cosmosdb collection

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I just started to scratch the surface with cosmosdb and I'm having issues with querying document.
My document looks like this:

```
{
    "id": "2",
    "url": "cars/toyota-auris",    
    "name": "Toyota Auris",
    "description": "Auris desc",
    "address": {
        "city": "Berlin"        
    },
    "_rid": "--4zAKfcoCgCAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/--2zAA==/colls/--4zAKfcoCg=/docs/--4zAKfcoCgCAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"23010db4-0000-0d00-0000-5f1b5f4a0000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1595629383
}

Partition key: address/city
```

I'm trying to retrieve the document using cosmosd .net sdk 3.

```
int id = "2";
ItemResponse<Car> response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<Car>(id, new PartitionKey(id));
return response.Resource;
```

This query ends up with exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException: 'Response status code does not indicate success: NotFound (404); Substatus: 0; ActivityId: c2c2bbff-5451-44af-a397-ca67088cce02; Reason: ({
  "Errors": [
    "Resource Not Found"
  ]
});'
```

What's interesting is that I'm able is query all documents using

```
_container.GetItemQueryIterator<Car>(new QueryDefinition("SELECT * FROM Cars"));
```

> What I'm doing wrong with querying single document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are querying using `id` as partition key, but your defined partition key is `address/city`. Since ReadItemAsync only looks in the specified partition, it won't find your item. If you want to do point reads, you need to choose a partition key you know in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated above you need to pass in the correct partition key value. Rewrite ReadItemAsync() similar to this.

```
int id = "2";
string pk = "Berlin";
ItemResponse<Car> response = await _container.ReadItemAsync<Car>(id, new PartitionKey(pk));
return response.Resource;
```